# using two modules with the same declared variables in the same program Fortran

Tags: module, fortran

i am making two modules to use them in the main program instead of a common blocks.
now i have two modules and both of them depends on the same variables like:

```
module A

implicit none

Save

INTEGER         z,x

PARAMETER       (z= 433, x= 400)

Real :: RM(z)

Real :: RP02(x)

.

.

.

.

end module A
```

and

```
module B

implicit none

Save 

INTEGER         z,x

PARAMETER       (z= 433, x= 400)

Real :: RPS02(z)

Real :: RDPS02(x)

.

.

.

.

end module B
```

and when i use them in my main program, the program has errors because of the same variables.

**any idea what shall i do ?**

Answer (score 2):

Use a third module:

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat 3_modules.f90 
Module array_sizes

  Implicit None

  Integer, Parameter, Public :: x = 400
  Integer, Parameter, Public :: z = 433

  Private

End Module array_sizes

Module a

  Use array_sizes, Only : x, z

  Implicit None

  Real, Dimension( 1:z ), Public :: rm
  Real, Dimension( 1:x ), Public :: rp02

  Private

End Module a

Module b

  Use array_sizes, Only : x, z

  Implicit None

  Real, Dimension( 1:z ), Public :: rps02
  Real, Dimension( 1:x ), Public :: rdps02

  Private

End Module b

Program testit

  Use a, Only : rm   , rp02
  Use b, Only : rps02, rdps02

  Implicit None

  Call Random_number( rm     ) 
  Call Random_number( rp02   ) 
  Call Random_number( rps02  ) 
  Call Random_number( rdps02 )

  Write( *, * ) 'Size rm    ', size( rm     )
  Write( *, * ) 'Size rp02  ', size( rp02   )
  Write( *, * ) 'Size rps02 ', size( rps02  )
  Write( *, * ) 'Size rdps02', size( rdps02 )

  Write( *, * ) rm( 1:4 ) * rps02( 1:4 )

End Program testit

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all 3_modules.f90 
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
 Size rm             433
 Size rp02           400
 Size rps02          433
 Size rdps02         400
   4.44743484E-02  0.322003543       3.06500960E-02  0.369239926    
ian@eris:~/work/stack$
```

Comment: First of all thank you i'm trying it now , but what shall i do if i have:
real :: QSIH(2,x,z) how i make it Real, Dimension( 1:x ), Public :: ??

Comment: Real, Dimension( 1:2, 1:x, 1:z ), Public :: qsih        - If you are having problems with that I suggest you study a book about Fortran before getting to deep in, Metcalf, Reid and Cohen is my preferred one.